# Show that $dE/dt = -bv^2$ (Help with differentiation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, differentiation, oscillators

The question is:

> Show that $$dE/dt = -b  (dx/dt)^2.$$

And the solution is:

```
1)E = 1/2 mv^2 + 1/2 kx^2

2)E = 1/2 m(dx/dt)^2 + 1/2 kx^2

3)dE/dt = 1/2 m2(d^2x/dt^2)(dx/dt) = 1/2 k2x(dx/dt)

4)m(d^2x/dt^2) = F = -kx - b(dx/dt)

5)dE/dt = (-kx -b(dx/dt))(dx/dt) + kx(dx/dt)

6)dE/dt = -b(dx/dt)^2
```

The part I don't understand is the 3rd line, where we differentiate. Specifically the differentiation of 1/2 kx^2. Shouldn't it just be equal to kx? why do we add the dx/dt? It's not like we're having to use the chain rule here, like we do during the differentiation of 1/2 m(dx/dt)^2. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use mathjax to properly format your equations. As it stands this is unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

> It's not like we're having to use the chain rule here, like we do during the differentiation of 1/2 m(dx/dt)^2. What am I missing?

That's precisely what we have to do, so that's what you're missing.

Comment: I thought the chain rule was used to differentiate composite functions, what is composite about a 1/2kx^2 ?

Comment: @Theo You are differentiating with respect to time, and $x$ is a function of time.

Comment: That's so obvious now that you've said it! Thanks!